# SaveChangesAsync returns Thread was being aborted

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have several hours trying to know why I have got the following exception type when I call `SaveChangesAsync();`

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll

I'm using EF6 code-first, following is my EntityModel

```
public class Visit
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Patient")]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Doctor")]
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VisitType")]
    public int VisitTypeId { get; set; }

    public DateTime VisitDate { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan ArrivalTime { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan? EnterToTestTime { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VisitStatus")]        
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan? CancelingTime { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string CancelingReason { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation Prop.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public virtual VisitType VisitType { get; set; }
    public virtual VisitStatus VisitStatus { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inverse Prop.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<VisitNote> VisitNotes { get; set; }
}
```

Following is function in my service layer class:

```
public async Task<bool> AddNewPatientVisit(IVisitModel vm)
    {
        using (var transaction = _unitOfWork.BeginTrainsaction())
        {
            try
            {
                var visit = new Visit
                {
                    UserId = vm.UserId,
                    DoctorId = vm.DoctorId,
                    PatientId = vm.PatientId,
                    StatusId = vm.StatusId,
                    VisitDate = DateTime.Now.Date,
                    ArrivalTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay,
                    VisitTypeId = vm.VisitTypeId,                        
                };

                await _unitOfWork.Visits.Insert(visit);
                await _unitOfWork.Save();

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The Save method:

```
public async Task<int> Save()
{
    try
    {
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return -1;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return -1;
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return -1;
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return -1;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return -1;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

with the stack trace of

```
at System.Utf8String.HashCaseInsensitive(Void* sz, Int32 cSz)
   at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.MemberInfoCache`1.GetListByName(Char* pName, Int32 cNameLen, Byte* pUtf8Name, Int32 cUtf8Name, MemberListType listType, CacheType cacheType)
   at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.MemberInfoCache`1.Populate(String name, MemberListType listType, CacheType cacheType)
   at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.MemberInfoCache`1.GetMemberList(MemberListType listType, String name, CacheType cacheType)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodCandidates(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, Boolean allowPrefixLookup)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
   at System.Type.GetMethod(String name)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DelegateFactory.CreatePropertySetter(Type entityDeclaringType, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Boolean allowNull)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DelegateFactory.GetSetterDelegateForProperty(EdmProperty property)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DelegateFactory.SetValue(EdmProperty property, Object target, Object value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.StateManagerMemberMetadata.SetValue(Object userObject, Object value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.SnapshotChangeTrackingStrategy.SetCurrentValue(EntityEntry entry, StateManagerMemberMetadata member, Int32 ordinal, Object target, Object value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapper`1.SetCurrentValue(EntityEntry entry, StateManagerMemberMetadata member, Int32 ordinal, Object target, Object value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.SetCurrentEntityValue(StateManagerTypeMetadata metadata, Int32 ordinal, Object userObject, Object newValue)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateEntryDbUpdatableDataRecord.SetRecordValue(Int32 ordinal, Object value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.PropagatorResult.SetServerGenValue(Object value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.BackPropagateServerGen(List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.<UpdateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStoreAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesInternalAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ECMS.DataAccess.Infrastructure.UnitOfWork.<Save>d__16.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ECMS\ECMS.DataAccess\Infrastructure\UnitOfWork.cs:line 49
```

Comment: please make sure your code is properly formatted, highlight the text and use the button that looks like `{ }` on the toolbar.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53026662/edit) and include the code of how you are calling `Save`, do this all the way up to the call stack till you can't go any higher. The problem is in a layer above save, not save itself.

Comment: Your question is a lot better, but the problem is not in the layers you added, the problem is in the function who calls `AddNewPatientVisit` or one of the layers above it.

Comment: Looks like your `_unitOfWork` is accessed in multiple threads.

Comment: All those catch statements simply returning the same result

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Mr. Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold)

> "My _unitOfWork is accessed in multiple threads"

I was instantiating my service layer class two times!